# Looking for Rhino Mocks conceptual documentation

Tags: rhino-mocks

I've recently started using Rhino Mocks and don't have a full understanding of its contexts, states and features, sometimes mistakenly comparing it too closely to other mocking frameworks. For example, the following sentence talks about a *[replay state](http://www.ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks/api/files/MockRepository-cs.html)* and that threw me for a bit:

```
A call to <Rhino.Mocks.MockRepository.ReplayAll> would move the mock 
object(s) to replay state, a call to <Rhino.Mocks.MockRepository.VerifyAll> 
is made from the [TearDown] method.
```

Can anybody point me to high level conceptual explanations online (technical would be best) of the various states, nuances and understandings needed to wield this tool well, (e.g. so I don't waste time forgetting to call `.ReplayAll()` and also so I know *why* I have to use replay).

The online documentation that I've seen seems to jump right into it. Am I missing a major piece of documentation, or must I skim online blogs and such, or buy a book to get the kind of high level conceptual intro that I'm asking for?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but this is the documentation for Rhino Mocks that I can never find when I need it:

http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+3.5.ashx

Comment: It's high level and somewhat conceptual but still doesn't seem to direct me toward some important concepts like what this replay thing is all about - I still feel it's lacking or maybe scattered about just out of reach. Thank you for the link because I didn't run across this info before and it is helpful.